# How to perferm different action depending on user input

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to make a really simple game (even without an interface). You are supposed to type what action would you like to do (attack or block), but I'm not having the best time trying to understand how to do it. I want it to be like this: if user types attack where is one course of action, is it is block than another, is it something else i want it to go back to asking what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        int hp = 10; //Not used yet
        int enemy_hp = 10;
        String attack;
        String block;
    int enemy_action = (int) (Math.random() * 1); //Not used yet
    int your_block_chance1 = (int) (Math.random() * 1);//Not used yet
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("It is your turn, attack or try to block");
    String action = userInput.next(); 
    System.out.println(action); 
    if (action.equals(attack)){
        System.out.print("You attacked your enemy and ");
        int enemy_block_chance1 = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        if (enemy_block_chance1 == 1) {
            System.out.print("he blocked it");
        }
        else if (enemy_block_chance1 != 1){
            enemy_hp = enemy_hp - 2;
            System.out.print("managed to hit, now his hp is " +enemy_hp);
        }
    }
    else if (action.equals(block)){

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if (action.equals(attack))
```

to:

```
if (action.equals("attack"))
```

(and do the same for the block action check)

At present, your String attack has not been set equal to "attack" and as it's not been initialized it's therefore just an empty string.

NOTE: You should also surround your code with a try/catch block to implement exception handling (i.e. so your program doesn't crash when the user enters an integer for example).